# Finding a non-numeric minimum value in js

Tags: javascript

I want to get the minimum of an array or iterable in JS.  The items are not necessarily numeric.

From what I can tell, the builtin `Math.min` doesn't offer the ability to specify a comparator function.

Is there a another built-in or standard way to accomplish this (common) task?

For example, a JS analogue to Python's `min` which accepts a `key` function or Java's `Collections.min` which accepts a `Comparator`.

My best approach so far is

```
array.reduce((a, e) => compare(a, e) < 0 ? a : e)
```

Comment: How about `Array#filter` ?

Comment: Actually reduce makes sense, but are you struck with your approach?

Comment: @Rayon I'm not sure how to take that approach other than possibly filter by comparing to all previous or following elements which would be less performant than reduce

Comment: @Siva: not stuck: it seems to work.  Wondering if there's a better (idiomatic/builtin) way to do it that I'm missing

Comment: @arcyqwerty: alright. I am not aware of any other approach in native javascript. But I had check lodash.js. They seem to have a `_.minBy` method which takes compare function as parameter https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#minBy

Comment: I'm just using native for now, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I don't understand this question, how do you determine what's a minimum value especially for a non-numeric thing?

Comment: @A.Lau: the comparator function would be able to compare `a` and `b` to determine which is "smaller".  This is an arbitrary function that takes in arbitrary inputs and can make a decision based on how it's implemented.

Comment: I kind of understand a bit, but I think it would be a bit clearer to me if you made an example, since I don't think you're just simply comparing two values.

Comment: Given `var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', ...];`, a comparator for ordering calendar months might be `(a, b) => months.indexOf(a) - months.indexOf(b)` such that `['Apr', 'Jan', 'Feb'].reduce((a, e) => compare(a, e) < 0 ? a : e)` produces `"Jan"`

Comment: This could get more complex, both in terms of the objects being compared (e.g. deeply nested objects) and in the comparison function (e.g. if I'm writing a spell checker that needs to determine which string has the smallest edit distance to a fixed string or if I'm writing an AI that needs to score possible choices)